# Retrofit Response body is null while isn't NULL in Postman

Tags: android, retrofit2, postman

I call a post request that register a user.I pass three field to API include name,email,password.My API is on localhost.Response is an object called 'response' and includes a list of String.Response format is here:

```
{
  "response": [
    "sample string"
  ]
}
```

When I receive response,always give me `422` status code.While I test it on `Postman`,I give `200` status code and correct response.In fact When I enter the inputs with correct format, I get a null response and program crashed.
This is `APIClient` class:

```
public class APIClient {
public static final String BASE_URL ="http://192.168.1.110:1996/api/";
private static Retrofit retrofit=null;


public static Retrofit getClient(){
    if(retrofit==null){
        retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

This is `APIInterface`:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("register")
Call<Sresponse>Register(@Field("name") String name,
                        @Field("email") String email,
                        @Field("password") String password);
```

This is `Sresponse` model:

```
public class Sresponse {
@SerializedName("response")
List<String> response;

public Sresponse(List<String> response) {
    this.response = response;
}

public List<String> getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public void setResponse(List<String> response) {
    this.response = response;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Sresponse{" +
            "response=" + response +
            '}';
}
}
```

And finally this code is where call request:

```
private void doRegister(){
    APIInterface apiInterface= APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    retrofit2.Call<Sresponse> call= apiInterface.Register(name,email,password);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Sresponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Sresponse> call, Response<Sresponse> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                result=response.body();       
              Log.e("MA",result.toString());
                }
            }else if(response.code()== 422){
                result=response.body();
                Log.e("MA",result.getResponse().toString()+" code 422");                 
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Sresponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("MA",t.toString());
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You are getting a 422, this is an UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY error. Maybe you have to add some parameter to your header. Review the headers you are using on Postman and emulate it.

Comment: If it is not the solution, maybe you should use `Parcelable` or `Serializable` for your entity class

Comment: No, my header has no another parameter. I test same request in `Postman` and receive correct response.

Comment: @GabrielMoreno I also used `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

422 means UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY, maybe its because @FormUrlEncoded mode, please check that have you the same problem in postman in x-wwww-form-urlencoded request mode.if it was the problem change your post request to normal mode with a proper object for your request body.

Comment: I try it with x-wwww-form-urlencoded request mode in postman and that is Ok.

Comment: oh ok, btw try the default mode maybe it helps you